# How can I find a value based on two parameters in this situation

Tags: excel, offset, vlookup

My situation is this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KgMlaHm.png]

How can I find how much money John made in City3, in the Year3? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4xPh.png)

I've tried to use Vlookup and Offset, but no luck. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Interested in implementing this using macros?

Comment: Nope, no VBA, no C#, no Java. I just want to see if is possible using only formulas.